# Using force field to rotate objects/particles?

Tags: particles, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, force-fields

I am trying to use some force field to affect rotation of a rigid body object or at least particles and fail miserably. Rotation checked, Location unchecked in field settings, tried cranking up strength, size, inflow, almost everything with every type of fields - nothing happens. Is anyone ever did this succesfully? Is there something I should know?

Comment: Hm. I've checked it seems not working without affect location. I suppose there is no much we can help with. Describe that your task is, so that we can try to find a workaround

Comment: @Crantisz Well, thank you for checking, at least now I know I'm not going insane. Not trying to do anything too specific, just experimenting with abstract animations with particles and objects moving and rotating in pattern and was hoping to use most straightforward way. I guess workarounds would be geo nodes or animation graph noise.